# Check whether there exists a plot already in R?

Tags: r, plot

Here is the situation:
I want to draw a graph(e.g, a line),but if there exists a plot already,then I will append the plot,i.e. `lines(...)`, otherwise I will draw new graph,i.e. `plot(....)`.
Thus how to check whether there exists a plot already before drawing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is very likely an xy problem, i.e. there is a simple solution to your actual problem but you focus on a difficult approach. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below function to view the list of active devices/plots. If it returns NULL then all of your devices/plots are off.

```
dev.list()
```

Comment: A device being open doesn't necessarily mean anything has been plotted.